# Get hours from unix timestamp

Tags: lua, timestamp

How can I get the current hour from a linux timestamp? I can get the year, month, day, minute, and second, but not the hour. Any help?

Current code:

```
local secondsPassed = os ~= nil and os.time() or tick()
local year = 1970 + math.floor(secondsPassed / (86400 * 365.25))
local days = math.floor((secondsPassed % (365.25 * 86400)) / 86400)
days = days + (year - 2011)
local minutes = math.floor((secondsPassed % 3600) / 60)
local seconds = math.floor(secondsPassed % 60)
```

Broken:

```
local hours = math.floor((secondsPassed % 86400) / 3600)-- +1
```

Comment: If your days is correct, then how can your hours/minutes/seconds be broken since they all rely on secondsPassed?

Comment: The only one broken is hours

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here:

- UNIX time is relative to midnight 1970-01-01, GMT. If you are not in GMT, you will see an offset that depends on your time zone. If your region observes daylight savings time, this offset will vary based on the date in a potentially rather complex fashion.
- Years are not 365.25 days long. They are either 365 or 366 days long, based on the year. (Which doesn't even average out to 365.25; due to special cases for years divisible by 100 and 400, it averages out to 365.2425.)

Unless there is some reason that you cannot use the Lua [`date` and `time` modules](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html), I would strongly recommend that you do so, rather than trying to recreate them yourself.

Comment: So if i don't add/subtract my timezone, it would seem wrong?   
  
I would use the os date and time modules, but [ROBLOX](http://roblox.com) doesn't let you use them.

Comment: Correct; failing to take the time zone into account will definitely give you the wrong hour. The other issues I mentioned will also apply, though.

Answer (score 0):

You were super close. I hours correct so far by:

local hours = math.floor((secondsPassed % 86400) / 1440) + 1